# How to store multiple inputs from users to the localStorage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

So i have a input field that ask for user to input a number:

```
<label for="amount"><b>Amount</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Number" name="number" id="number" required>
```

What i want to do is store that in the localStorage:
here's my script:

```
var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
var aNumber = [];
aNumber.push(number);
localStorage.setItem('number',JSON.stringify(aNumber));
```

the script works however, when the user inputs a new value it overwrites the old one. Thus storing only one value all the time. 
I want it so that it will store all values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will overwrite because you're always creating a new array, instead of utilizing the old array if it exists. You need to change your code as follows:

```
var aNumber = !!localStorage.getItem('number') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('number')) : [];
var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
aNumber.push(number);
localStorage.setItem('number', JSON.stringify(aNumber));
```

The above code  checks for the existence of the array first, and if it exists, then the code uses the same array, else creates a new array.

PS: This code will eventually become too slow as the number of items increase in the array because of repeated execution of `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` methods.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work in stackoverflow because localStorage is disabled, but you can see this in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fvcym5qp/):

```js
var aNumber = [];
document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('change', function(event) { 
    var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
    aNumber.push(number);
    localStorage.setItem('number',JSON.stringify(aNumber));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('number'));
});
```

```html
<label for="amount"><b>Amount</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Number" name="number" id="number" required>
```

Most likely you were overwriting the `aNumber` array every time.

Answer (score 0):

The below code won't work on Stack Overflow due to origin blocking for saving against local storage. Here is a fiddle that will showcase this: https://jsfiddle.net/612s5ack/1/

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var isNotBlank = function(str) {
    if (typeof str !== 'string') {
      return false;
    }
    return !(!str || /^\s*$/.test(str));
  };

  var isBoolean = function(bool) {
    return typeof bool === 'boolean';
  };

  var saveToLocalStorage = function(key, value, nullable) {

    // failsafe to make sure that default action is to prevent
    // null/undefined/blank values from being saved
    if (!isBoolean(nullable)) {
      nullable = false;
    }

    if (isNotBlank(key) === true && (nullable === true || (nullable === false && isNotBlank(value) === true))) {
      var message = null;
      // Check to see if local storage is available
      if (typeof(localStorage) === 'undefined') {
        message = 'Local Storage is not supported by this browser.';
        console.log(message);
        return message;
      } else {
        try {
          localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        } catch (exception) {
          message = 'Local Storage error occurred on save: ' + exception.message;
          console.log(message);
          return message;
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var getItemFromLocalStorage = function(key) {
    if (isNotBlank(key) === true) {
      if (typeof(localStorage) === 'undefined') {
        var message = 'Local Storage is not supported by this browser.';
        console.log(message);
        return null;
      } else {
        try {
          return localStorage.getItem(key);
        } catch (exception) {
          message = 'Local Storage error occurred on delete: ' + exception.message;
          console.log(message);
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
  };
  
  var save = function() {
    var aNumber = [];
    var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
    var localStorageSaved = getItemFromLocalStorage('number');
    if (localStorageSaved !== null) {
      aNumber = JSON.parse(localStorageSaved);
    }
    aNumber.push(number);
    saveToLocalStorage('number', JSON.stringify(aNumber));
  };

</script>
<label for="amount"><b>Amount</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Number" name="number" id="number" required/>
<input type="button" id="save" value="Save Number" onclick="save();" />
```